# I run ISNUMERIC('<string>') in SQL Server 2008 level 80, but it return 1, not 0

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I run code `SELECT ISNUMERIC('121212,12')` in level 80 in SQL Server 2008 R2, but it return 1, not 0.

I read in page Microsoft this code will return 0 in level 80 and return 1 in level 90. [Link reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/bb510680(v=sql.105)#remarks)

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC('121212,12')
```

Why it return 1 in level 80?

Answer (score 2):

The ANSI/ISO SQL standard (and SQL Server) uses `.` as a decimal separator, not comma, so this `ISNUMERIC` class test will fail. As to why this works in 80 (SQL 2000 compatibility level), the more strict behavior for `ISNUMERIC` was [a change introduced in SQL 2005](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms178653(v=sql.90)). In SQL Server 2000 and compatibility level 80, commas are ignored entirely so even an egregiously invalid value will return 1, such as `ISNUMERIC(',123,,45678.89,,,')` whereas this will return 0 in later levels.

The compatibility table in the old SQL Server 2005 documentation regarding this behavior is incorrect, with the 80 and 90 behavior listed backwards, which may have led to your question. Below is the actual behavior and how it should have been documented.

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                       Compatibility-level setting of 80                       |                         Compatibility-level setting of 90                         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| In SELECT ISNUMERIC('<string>'), embedded commas within <string> are ignored. | In SELECT ISNUMERIC('<string>'), embedded commas within <string> are significant. |
| For example, the following SELECT ISNUMERIC('121212,12') query returns 1.     | For example, the following SELECT ISNUMERIC('121212,12') query returns 0.         |
| This indicate that the string 121212,12 is numeric.                           | This indicates that the string 121212,12 is not numeric.                          |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Also, be aware that `ISNUMERIC` will return 1 for values you may not want to consider as numeric (e.g. empty string, '1E', etc.). Consider using an alternate method. Unfortunately, the more robust `TRY_CONVERT` and `TRY_CAST` functions are not available until SQL Server 2012 so you need to use a technique such as `LIKE` if you need more strict parsing in earlier versions. Importantly, SQL Server 2008 R2 support ends next month (along with compatibility level 80) so an upgrade would be the best long-term solution, allowing the use of `TRY_PARSE/TRY_CONVERT`.

Comment: I try SELECT ISNUMERIC('123.23'), but it return 1

Comment: `ISNUMERIC('123.23')` should return 1 since that is a numeric literal. Isn't that what you expect?

Comment: I try it in SQL server 2008 R2, level 80. In level 80, I expect 0

Comment: @NganMai, I think your confusion is due to a mistake in the old documentation. I've updated my answer to detail that.